# Jasmine how do I set the response of a spy

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have the following in my Angular.js controller

```
function alreadyRegistered() {
    if(reg.regForm.email.$valid){
        console.log('this is logged in my console.');
        authFactory.doesUserExist(reg.user)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log('this line if never hit');
                if(response) {
                    reg.regForm.email.$setValidity('userExists', false);
                } else {
                    reg.regForm.email.$setValidity('userExists', true);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                reg.error = err;
            });
    } else { 
        reg.regForm.email.$setValidity('userExists', true); // Remove userExists validation error.
    }
};
```

I would like to test that the validation is working correctly by setting the response inside the .then() to either true or false. However I can not get my test to go inside the .then().

Here's my test:

```
describe('Registration Controller Tests', function() {
    var $controller, $scope, defer, doesUserExistSpy, authFactory, Registration,

    beforeEach(module('enigma'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, $q, $injector) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_;
        defer = $q.defer();

        // Create spies
        doesUserExistSpy = jasmine.createSpy('doesUserExist').and.returnValue(defer.promise);

        authFactory = {
            register: registerSpy,
            doesUserExist: doesUserExistSpy
        };    

        // Init register controller with mocked services
        Registration = $controller('Registration', {
            $scope: $scope,
            authFactory: authFactory,
            $state: $state
        });

        // digest to update controller with services and scope
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    describe('check email field validity', function () {
        var element, regForm;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            $scope = $rootScope;
            element = angular.element(
                '<form name="regForm">' + 
                    '<input type="email" ng-model="test.email" name="email" value="bwayne@wayneenterprise.com" />' +
                '</form>'
            );
            $compile(element)($scope);
            regForm = $scope.regForm;
        }));

        it('should set regForm.email.$error.userExists to true if /doesUserExist returns true', function () {
            $httpBackend.whenPOST('/doesUserExist').respond(defer.resolve(true)); // I'm trying to set the value for 'response' in the .then() for the controller.
            Registration.alreadyRegistered();
            $scope.$digest();
            expect(regForm.email.$error.userExists).toEqual(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's my authFactory code:

```
angular
    .module('enigma.authFactory', [])    
    .factory('authFactory', authFactory);

authFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function authFactory($window, $http, $q, sessionStorageFactory){
    var auth = {
        doesUserExist: doesUserExist
    };

    return auth;

    function doesUserExist(email){
        var defered = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/app/doesUserExist', email)
            .success(function(data){
                if(data.message !== 'user exists'){
                    defered.resolve(false);
                } else {
                    defered.resolve(true);
            }
        });
        return defered.promise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code of `authFactory` service `doesUserExist` method?

Comment: It is some request using $http, right?

Comment: What is real response to `/doesUserExist`?

Comment: I have added my AuthFactory code.

Comment: Deleted my answer, it is wrong :) You need [Unit Testing with $q Promises in AngularJS](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are completely mocking out your `authFactory` service, you don't need to touch `$httpBackend`. Simply resolve the `defer` object that is returned by your mock. For example

```
it('should set regForm.email.$error.userExists to true if /doesUserExist returns true', function () {
    Registration.alreadyRegistered();
    expect(doesUserExistSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    defer.resolve(true);
    $scope.$apply();

    expect(regForm.email.$error.userExists).toEqual(true);
});
```